# R latex2exp switch back to non-subscript

Tags: r, latex

Trying out the R latex2exp package and having trouble with syntax.  Trying to create a label with the text Z(u + subscripted alpha symbol then ).  Can't work out how to get the subscript for the alpha to discontinue do the closing bracket is not subscripted.

Example R code

```
require(latex2exp)
plot(1,2)
text(1,2,TeX('Z(u$_\\alpha$)'),cex = 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Curly brackets will do the thing:

```
plot(1, 2, pch = 19)
text(1, 2.4, latex2exp::TeX('$Z(u_{\\alpha})$'), cex = 4)
```

[image: TeX]

See also `latex2exp::latex2exp_examples()`